# COUNT no muestra valor en 0, SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente código y quiero mostrar todos mis campos con **`SQL`** pero como el **count** de **E**.falla tiene un valor nulo no muestra nada de ese campo, alguna sugerencia?

```
SELECT B.id,B.linea,B.DateTime,B.EndDate,C.id_employee,A.id_empatarollos, SUM(psb_produc) AS TotalProduction ,
 SUM(psb_rate) AS TotalRateExpect, 
SUM(scrap) AS TotalScrap, COUNT(E.falla) AS FallasFTQ 

    FROM psb_smt.psb_produccion A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN psb_smt.psb_info B ON A.id_psbinfo = B.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN psb_smt.psb_employees C ON A.id_employee = C.id_employee 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN psb_smt.psb_employees D ON A.id_empatarollos = D.id_employee 
    LEFT JOIN sisma.registroproblemaaoi E ON A.psb_line = E.linea 

    WHERE A.DateTime>= '2019-09-23 06:40:00' AND 
    A.DateTime <= '2019-09-23 16:10:00' AND 
    A.psb_hr = '5' AND 
    E.id_hora='5' AND 
    E.fecha='2019-09-23' 

    GROUP by B.linea
```

---

Esta es mi consulta...

```html
SELECT E.id_hora, A.psb_hr, E.fecha, B.linea,B.DateTime,B.EndDate,C.id_employee,A.id_empatarollos, SUM(psb_produc) AS TotalProduction, 
 SUM(psb_rate) AS TotalRateExpect, SUM(scrap) AS TotalScrap, COUNT(E.id_hora) AS FallasFTQ
FROM psb_smt.psb_produccion A
 INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_info B 
  ON A.id_psbinfo = B.id
 INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_employees C 
  ON A.id_employee = C.id_employee
 INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_employees D 
  ON A.id_empatarollos = D.id_employee
 INNER JOIN sisma.registroproblemaaoi E 
  ON A.psb_line = E.linea
WHERE A.DateTime>= '2019-09-24 06:40:00'  AND A.DateTime <= '2019-09-24 16:10:00' AND E.fecha='2019-09-24'
 AND E.id_hora = '4' AND A.psb_hr = '4'
GROUP by A.psb_line, E.id_hora;
```

Lo que me muestra...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo espero que muestre son los datos sin importar que en mi otra base de datos no exista el conteo de "Fallas" que me ponga un 0.

Cuando existe un registro en ambos si obtengo lo que quiero pero tambien ocupo mostrar informacion aunque no haya fallas que contar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquiya me muestra informacion por que con el dato "8" ya informacion en las dos base de datos..

Espero se pueda entender a lo que quiero llegar, gracias.

Comment: es por que no existe una relación de tus registros con  sisma.registroproblemaaoi

Comment: Para subir preguntas, te recomiendo: nombres mas intuitivos y http://sqlfiddle.com para que podamos hacer pruebas.

Comment: Para que tu pregunta esté autocontenida y sea un ejemplo mínimo verificable, procura indicar: versión de BD, scripts de creación de las tablas involucradas y unos datos de prueba con la salida esperada. Cualquier consulta SQL es correcta dependiendo del resultado esperado :)

Comment: La relacion que tengo de una tabla a otra es la A.psb_line y E.linea por que contienen el mismo dato

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres que muestre? Si no hay valores que contar, entonces se debe mostrar un cero.

Comment: Modifique la publicacion para lograr explicar que es lo que quiero..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas un LEFT JOIN para que te permita regresar filas cuando no haya filas correspondientes en una tabla. También necesitas cambiar condiciones del WHERE al JOIN.

```
SELECT  E.id_hora, 
        A.psb_hr, 
        E.fecha, 
        B.linea,
        B.DateTime,
        B.EndDate,
        C.id_employee,
        A.id_empatarollos, 
        SUM(psb_produc) AS TotalProduction, 
        SUM(psb_rate) AS TotalRateExpect, 
        SUM(scrap) AS TotalScrap, 
        COUNT(E.id_hora) AS FallasFTQ
FROM psb_smt.psb_produccion A
    INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_info B 
        ON A.id_psbinfo = B.id
    INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_employees C 
        ON A.id_employee = C.id_employee
    INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_employees D 
        ON A.id_empatarollos = D.id_employee
    LEFT JOIN sisma.registroproblemaaoi E 
        ON A.psb_line = E.linea
         AND E.fecha='2019-09-24'
         AND E.id_hora = '4'
WHERE A.DateTime >= '2019-09-24 06:40:00'  AND A.DateTime <= '2019-09-24 16:10:00' AND A.psb_hr = '4'
GROUP by A.psb_line, E.id_hora;
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono a la perfeccion amigo